# Flex 4 - How to convert string(yyyy/mm/dd) to date object?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am taking date input from DateField in flex. And I have an XML file with date in YYYY/MM/DD format i.e string format. How to convert this string to Date object? And I have to compare these two values?

I am getting "Tue Feb 4 00:00:00 GMT-0800 2014" this type of output from the DateField selection. And I have to use "dateCompare()" function(It's like restriction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date.parse function should work with that format  , if is not working you can use the Array.split to get the values you need,

```
var d:Date=new Date();
var matches:Array=string.split("/");
d.setUTCFullYear(int(matches[0]), int(matches[1]) - 1, int(matches[2]))
```

To Set the time you can use the method setUTCHours

[see documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#setUTCHours%28%29)

```
d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)
```

EDIT:

```
var string:String="2008/11/13";
            var d:Date=new Date();
            var matches:Array=string.split("/");
            d.setUTCFullYear(int(matches[0]), int(matches[1]) - 1, int(matches[2]))
            trace(d);
             d.setUTCHours(12,11,13);
            trace(d);
```

Comment: I am getting output like this "Sun Jul 12 17:00:00 GMT-0700 9". Can I set the time as 0, which means "Sun Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-0700 9". Is it  possible?

Comment: @user why is not working? check my edit I added a block of code that runs great here

Comment: I can't understand. It give's some strange output. My output is like: Thu Nov 13 12:54:58 GMT-0800 2008
Thu Nov 13 04:11:13 GMT-0800 2008.

Comment: that is not strange, you get a Date object and if you want to print it in a specific format you need to convert it to a string, check the DateFormatter

Answer (score 1):

The simpler way is to use the parseDateStrig static method from mx.formatters.DateFormatter

```
var date:Date = DateFormatter.parseDateString("2013/1/11", "YYYY/MM/DD");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I use to do something similar. You can adapt it to fit your needs.

```
public static function convertSQLDate( dateString : String ) : Date
{
    if( dateString == null ) return null;

    var datePattern : RegExp = /(\d{4})-(\d+)-(\d+)( (\d+):(\d+):(\d+))?/;
    var result : Object = datePattern.exec( dateString );

    if( result[ 4 ] != null ) return new Date( result[1], result[2] - 1, result[3], result[ 5 ], result[ 6 ], result[ 7 ] );
    else return new Date( result[1], result[2] - 1, result[3] );            

}
```

Comment: It giving an error on the if condition. "Error 1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." Sorry I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTimeFormatter... for specific format....then check with your xml data.

s:DateTimeFormatter id="datePattern" dateTimePattern="yyyy/MM/dd"

if(datePattern.format(dateChooser.selectedDate) == "2014/03/01")

lblCheck.text = "Check...";

else

lblCheck.text = "Not Check..";

Use below link for DateTimeFormatter...

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS8b1c39bd7e9fc364-70b5c6d212c98ca85e2-8000.html